# Как постоянно проверять имеется ли подключение к интернету?

Tags: android

К примеру включили интернет, вывелось соответствующее сообщение, потом отключили его и опять получили соответствующее сообщение.

Те мониторить состояние интернета в любой момент времени, а не единоразово

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам нужно не *мониторить состояние интернета*, а *получать уведомления о его изменении*

Определение состояния подключения в момент времени:

```
boolean checkInternet(Context context) {   

    ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

BroadcastReceiver на изменение состояния сети:

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override 
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    if(checkInternet(context)){ 
         Toast.makeText(context, "Network Available Do operations",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    } 

}
```

И в манифесте определить сам ресивер:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="<ваш.пакет.сюда>.NetworkChangeReceiver ">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

И обязательно пермишен на получение состояния сети:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Получаем `ConnectivityManager` и выбираем какие броадкасты будем слушать:

```
connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
BroadcastReceiver connectivityStatusReceiver = new NetworkConnectionStatusReceiver();
```

Когда нужно начать мониторить состояние интернета запускаем прослушку соответствующих интентов:

```
context.registerReceiver(connectivityStatusReceiver, NETWORK_INTENT_FILTER))
```

Ну и собсно проверяем наличие интернета:

```
protected boolean hasConnection() {
    NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        switch (netInfo.getType()) {
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE:
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI:
            case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIMAX:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private class NetworkConnectionStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (hasConnection()) {
            // network available
        } else {
            // no network
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Только очень часто сеть продолжает быть подклченной, а вот интернета уже на деле нет.

Comment: Ну и да, если на устройствеах больше одного сетевого подключения(а это 99% случаев так есть) - hasConnection всегда будет выдавать true, даже если отключился сетевой интерфейс через которое были подключены к интернету. Вы сейчас проверяете вовсе не подключение к интернету, а просто наличие хоть одного подключенного сетевого интерфейса.

Comment: Для выполнения задачи нужно как минимум в hasConnection добавить код, который будет пытатся подключится к какому-либо интернет-ресурсу.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov я привел наиболее быстрый и простой способ проверки, которого во многих случаях вполне достаточно. Если же есть необходимость проверять доступность более тщательно, то логичнее всего будет в случае получения текущим методом сигнала что соединение есть - попытаться выполнить какойнибудь простейший запрос к своему АПИ (если есть), для оптимизации можно сделать HEAD запрос. Но реализация этого запроса будет зависить от того как в приложении реализована работа с АПИ, а потому не думаю что имеет какой то смысл приводить здесь примеры, слишком много вариантов.